# How to Find the Url of the Current Request?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Am building an autoupdate DLL in .net, a function in DLL gets url as input parameter and check the domain is registered on server or not.

For that, how can i get the url of the page from the DLL without knowing the programmer in aspx pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`

Comment: but still it can be assigned with some url

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for your response ----------var url = new Uri("http://google.com");  and that url can be assigned to the HttpContext.Current.Request.Url----------- but am not sure, do u think the programmer can be able to pass some other url other than the current page url to the DLL functon which accepts url as input parameter.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` cannot be changed by the developer. It is always the URL of the current request.